# Please clarify scenario about contour integral over closed path

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Contour integral:

> If function $f:\Bbb C-\{0\}\to\Bbb C$ continuous function on punctured domain.Suppose anti derivative for $f$ exists everywhere except $\{0\}$ then on a closed contour $C$, which does not pass through origin, $\int_Cf(z)\,dz=0$.

Am I correct above?

If I am correct, then why $\int_C \frac1z\,dz=0$ does not hold? ($\operatorname{Log} z$ is derivative of $1/z$ except at zero, right?)

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not correct, precisely because $\int_C\frac1z\,\mathrm dz\neq0$ for some closed contours. And there is no differentiable function $\operatorname{Log}\colon\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ such that $(\forall z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}):\operatorname{Log}'(z)=\frac1z$. The map $z\mapsto\frac1z$ only has a antiderivative locally, not globally.

Comment: So, am I correct about my first statement, that is, when anti derivative exists, then contour integral is zero?

Comment: Sure. Because if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ and if the domain of $C$ is $[a,b]$, then$$\int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm dz=F\bigl(C(b)\bigr)-F\bigl(C(a)\bigr)=0.$$